# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\AppServ\www\wordpress\wp-includes\link-template.php on line 2639

Tags: php, wordpress

this is the code the site was working in 000webhost but in my local hist 
it don't work

```
if ( 'newest' == get_option('default_comments_page') ) {
        if ( $pagenum != $max_page ) {
            if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
                $result = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit($result) . $wp_rewrite->comments_pagination_base . '-' . $pagenum, 'commentpaged');
            else
                $result = add_query_arg( 'cpage', $pagenum, $result );
        }
} elseif ( $pagenum > 1 ) {
        if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
            $result = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit($result) . $wp_rewrite->comments_pa
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess which line is 2639?

Comment: The last one

"$result = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit($result) . $wp_rewrite->comments_pa"

Comment: Well, that speaks for it's self? missing closing bracket? and missing end of your elseif `}`

Comment: and even missing opening bracket of last if, plus `;` at the end of the allready truncated line `...$wp_rewrite->comments_pa`.